# How to display the content of the volume?

Tags: openshift, volume

How to display the content of the openshift volume? (files that are in, the total space used etc.).

The only information I've managed to find in [the docs](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/volumes.html) is to `oc rsh` into the running POD and use `ls`, which of course is no way a viable solution if no pod using the volume is running and can't be started because of some issues with the volume...

Comment: If your application isn't starting because of data corruption, use ``oc debug`` against the deployment. That will give you shell with volume mounted but will not start your application.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment there's no "volume file explorer" or whatever interface in Openshift.
Currently you always need to attach the volume to a running pod and list files within.
If you're using glusterfs (and are cluster/storage admin) all volumes are also mounted inside the storage pods , so you can get a complete overview within the storage pods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know these ways are fit for you, but I just list the availabilities as follows.

As far as I remember, if the `pod` can be created based on `docker image`, then you can run without run the application like this.

```
oc run tmp-pod --image=your-docker-registry.default.svc/yourapplication  -- tail -f /dev/null
```

You are using `PersistentVolume`(`PV`/`PVC` pair) for your `volume`, then you can display the `volume` after mounting temporarily the `PV` to temporary pod as follows.

```
oc run tmp-pod --image=registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7  -- tail -f /dev/null
oc set volume dc/tmp-pod --add -t pvc --name=new-registry --claim-name=new-registry --mount-path=/mountpath
```

You can see the volume contents mounted above configuration via tmp-pod, and you can remove above temporary pod simply after checking.

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @Daein Park to display the `PersistentVolume`(`PV`/`PVC` pair) content was not working for me. The command `oc run tmp-pod` does not create a `dc` `deploymentConfig` and it seems impossible to set a volume to a pod.

My solution was to use the following command:

```
oc run tmp-pod --image=dummy --restart=Never --overrides='{"spec":{"containers":[{"command":["tail","-f","/dev/null"],"image":"registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7","name":"tmp-pod","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/mountpath","name":"volume"}]}],"volumes":[{"name":"volume","persistentVolumeClaim":{"claimName":"pv-clain"}}]}}'
```

> **NOTE2**: The `--image=dummy` is only provided to make the `oc run` command happy, anyway the image field is overridden the json.

Finally, to list the content of the mounted volume:

```
oc rsh tmp-pod ls /mountpath
```

---

As the json content is not easy to read in the command line, here is what it is provided to the `--overrides` parameter:

```
{
"spec": {
    "containers": [{
            "command": ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"],
            "image": "registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7",
            "name": "tmp-pod",
            "volumeMounts": [{
                    "mountPath": "/mountpath",
                    "name": "volume"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [{
            "name": "volume",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                "claimName": "pv-clain"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}